# Slim: Append text to printed Ruby variable

Tags: slim-lang

I have the following Slim snippet:

```
a href = data.api.docs Clicky
```

**What the output is:**

`<a href="https://docs.example.com/api">Clicky</a>`

**What I want the output to be:**

`<a href="https://docs.example.com/api#some-subsection">Clicky</a>`

How do I append the `#some-subsection` to the URL variable in Slim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out .. I just had to do:

```
a href = data.api.docs+"#some-subsection" Clicky
```

.. to generate:

```
<a href="https://docs.example.com/api#some-subsection">Clicky</a>
```